# How Can I Safely Move /var to a New Disk or Partition

Tags: filesystems, rhel, systemd

I'm working with a client that has their own VM images of RHEL 7 that they want to use for a project. Unfortunately, all of / is only  50GB. I asked for /var to be 300GB but all they did was mount a raw 300GB Disk onto the VM.

How can I safely move everything in /var to this new 300GB disk?

I initially attempted to follow [these instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-var-directory-to-another-partition) which seemed sensible but after a reboot broke just about everything. Polkit wouldn't start, which meant I couldn't control systemd, and I couldn't reboot. So I'm very wary of trying that way again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving /var, /home to separate partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131311/moving-var-home-to-separate-partition)

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Yes, closed as duplicate. It didn't come up in Stack Exchange search at first. I'll have to attempt this a handful of more times, but the key is to go into single user mode. Many services write to /var so stopping the services will present a folder that changes much less, allowing for a stable state. This can be difficult since you may not have access to that type of boot mode, I.E. on a VPS.